# Gwan API wrappers and mono_add_internal_call

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke, g-wan

I am using G-WAN 4.11.20

init.c

```
#pragma link "mono-2.0"
#pragma include "/home/igor/Projects/gwan_linux64-bit/mono-3.0.2"
#include "gwan.h"  // G-WAN API
#include <mono/metadata/metadata.h>
#include <mono/metadata/loader.h>
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>

static MonoString*  Sample ()
{
   return mono_string_new (mono_domain_get (), "Hello!");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   mono_add_internal_call("Gwan::Sample", Sample);
   return 0;
}
```

gwan_api.cs

```
public class Gwan
{
     [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
     extern public static string Sample();
}
```

gwan is starting with assertion:

ghashtable.c:236: assertion 'hash != NULL' failed

Than after calling script, I am getting the same problem.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot find the requested method.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gwan:Sample ()
  at hello2.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot find the requested method.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gwan:Sample ()
  at hello2.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My feeling is that I don't configure mono right, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `main.c` (the *maintenance* script) the `init.c` script must terminate for the G-WAN server to start listening.

Since the `init.c` code is released after its execution, this makes it a poor candidate for storing persistent code supposed to be called by G-WAN servlets to build dynamic contents for client requests.

You probably woul have more chances with `main.c`, or a G-WAN connection handler.

Comment: Make it working, as I wanted, thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting, looks like REQUEST and many of get_env data is cleared   when I am inside cs servlet. Why not clear it after execution?

Comment: The request context is (partially) cleared after the request has been processed and then totally cleared after a connection close (not while a servlet is executing). Check that you are accessing the 'right' information context by checking the value of the client socket from your servlet.

Comment: This is "cs" servlet. I am calling a function in C handler, that for example call get_env with REQUEST. While as result I see only GET /?hello.cs without all other data. Because of that, I need to make strdup and set it globally.

Comment: I guess you are referring to URL parameters. They are still there but  you need to read the buffer until you reach the end of the URI (with " HTTP/1.1 "), and skip the null characters used to separate each URL parameter.

Comment: QUERY_STRING is empty too. How do you know, did you try it?

Comment: I certainly could not try from C# as I would need your code to do so. I am referring to the behavior for C, which applies to C#: the request is sliced and diced while parsed. As a consequence, if you wish to read the READ xbuffer directly then you have to read NULL-byte-separated parameters until you reach the end of the URI (which is marked by the protocol version "HTTP/1.x").

Answer (score -1):

You must implement the C# wrappers for any new G-WAN API (or external function) you want to support from your C# scripts.

See [Gwan C#, how to get HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323412/gwan-c-how-to-get-http-headers)

Comment: Loading your persistent code from an ephemeral module. Thanks 'Pete' for the quick reply.